# How to remove a persistent URL redirect malware/virus from PC?

Tags: malware

I have a Windows laptop infected with a URL redirection software. I downloaded the [Kaspersky TDSSKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/us/viruses/disinfection/5350) and followed the instructions to remove them. But it is not effective and the URL redirect is still active.

When the URL redirect takes me to an incorrect web-page, I correct the address and go to the wanted page by manually typing the address. If I continue using the same tab in Chrome for web-pages such as `cnn.com` and `espn.com`, then that tab starts displaying ads from `ad.xtendmedia.com`.

What is the best way to remove the URL redirection and the ads from `ad.xtendmedia.com`? I have tried some of the other suggestions from other web-sites, such as disabling add-ons, etc. but there is not effect. Please let me know if this is not the right forum for asking such questions.

Comment: update your browser it will fix  all problems.

Comment: @Ayodhya That's the most untrue thing I have ever heard.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards in my case whenever I open firefox it was redirecting a page (it was not home page) when I updated, got all problem fixed.

Comment: @Ayodhya Maybe in your case, but not necessarily with someone other's problem.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to remove this particular infection without deleting anything else. But there are no general instructions on how to accomplish this in the general case. The instructions would have to be specifically tailored to your specific situation, and take in to account all the minutiae and particulars which can't feasibly be communicated in a question-and-answer format.

The only "known safe" advice that anyone can give is this:

> Start over with a clean and empty OS installation

This always works.